# Imacros instagram script issue

Tags: imacros

I was using the following script which was working fine up till yesterday..

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*5 + 3); 
randomNumber;")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Like
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Next
WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR1}}
```

Somehow the like button is not being recognized anymore.. Would really appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score -1):

I have run into the same problem and haven't figured out a fix for the "TAG" method, the work around is to use the click function... this is a little annoying because you have to figure out the coordinates (you can download a browser extension to do this) and write new code, the size of the window and size of the picture will change the location of the like button however... so you need a way to normalize where the button is on each new photo...

sample code:
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEMOVE POINT="(50, 630)" BUTTON=0 
EVENT TYPE=CLICK POINT="(50, 630)" BUTTON=2